# How to read csv with timedeltas and NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, timedelta

I'm trying to read a csv file that looks like this:

```
              col 1             col 2             col 3      ...     col N
0        0 days 00:00:16   0 days 00:00:07   0 days 00:01:02          NaN
.
.
.
15000    0 days 01:40:00         NaN               NaN       ...      NaN
```

What I've tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',', index_col=0, dtype=object)
df = df.applymap(lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x))
```

but as I have a lot of columns and rows, it is somewhat slow. Is there a more proper way to do this?

Comment: `parse_dates` in pandas.read_csv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

timedelta objects are not supported by either the `parse_dates` or `dtype` parameters in `read_csv`. Here are a couple of alternatives.

#### `apply` with `pd.to_timedelta`

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_timedelta, errors='coerce')
```

Or,

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = pd.to_timedelta(df[c], errors='coerce')
```

---

#### `pd.read_csv` with `converters=` argument

Another option is to pass a `converters` argument while loading:

```
f = {i : pd.to_timedelta for i in range(N)}  # you can access columns by index
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',', index_col=0, converters=f)
```

Comment: The first solution gets it quite nicely. I like the second one as well but, a priori, I don't know the value of N.

Comment: @JordiSalinasSanMartín Ah, you could get around that by reading the first line and counting the number of commas, or something along those lines... But that's more trouble than it's worth, so if the first method works, you have my permission to use it!

Comment: Just in case someone has only one column to be interpreted as timedelta, it works like this: `df.column_name = df.column_name.apply(pd.to_timedelta, errors='coerce')` where `column_name` is the actual column to be changed.